# Can I use a 2N3904 transistor in place of a 2N4401 if I flip it around?

Tags: transistors

I want to do a composite video mod for a `Colecovision`.  The mod (http://www.benheck.com/Games/Coleco/Video_Mod.htm) calls for an `NPN 2N4401-ND`.

The only NPN transistor I currently have is the `2N3904`.  However, the pins are reversed.

Could I simply flip the transistor around and use it? So that the pin that goes to the collector goes to my collector, etc.?

Thanks

Comment: The 2n3904 & 2n4401 have the same pinout.  We use them interchangeably in places where either will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to these two datasheets, one for the [2N3904](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/2N3904%28TO-92%29.pdf) and the other for the [2N4401](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/2N4401%28TO-92%29.pdf), they have the same pin configuration, namely E B C with the flat side facing you.

[image]

Looking at the other parameters of the datasheets, they look very similar (the h\$_{FE}\$ of the 2N3904 is just slightly higher), so you should be able to get by with the substitution.

Comment: Yep.  I must have had the wrong datasheet or something because I read it as being opposite.  But the video mod worked like a treat with that transistor.  Now I have composite video/audio on my `ColecoVision`!  Sweet.